# Convert Object in xml with NSXmlParser

Tags: objective-c, xml

I've the following Objective-C class definition:

```
//Book.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Book : NSObject {

NSInteger bookID;
NSString *title;
NSString *author;
NSString *summary;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *author;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *summary;

@end

//Book.m
#import "Book.h"

@implementation Book

@synthesize title, author, summary;

- (void) dealloc {

[summary release];
[author release];
[title release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Now I'd like to convert the variables (title, author, summary) into attributes of a XML-File. The XML-File should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Book 
title="Lord of the Rings" 
author="J.R.R Tolkien" 
summary="A long time ago" >
</Book>
```

My first way was to write the values of the variables into a NSString and then to produce a NSData *xmlData, which I filled with these NSStrings. But thats really just for let i work.

Has anyone a better idea to convert an objective-c class into an xml-file or are there any XML-Parser for objective-c, which implements this function (haven't found one yet)?

Thanks alot

Greets

Answer (score 2):

It's me again :D

I found a solution for my problem --> https://github.com/skjolber/xswi